# IIS ASP.NET css/js files not updating until forced page refresh

Tags: iis-7, release, browser-cache

When we do releases in IIS 7, we deploy new code to the releases directory on the server and then repoint the website in IIS to the new code directory.  For example:

Change website directory from C:\company\releases\code-5-17-12 to C:\company\releases\code-5-26-12.

This strategy lets us revert back to a previous release in a worst-case scenario.  However, the issue I'm having is that when a user who has been on the site goes to a page, sometimes they might need to explicitly refresh a page in order to get the new updated code.

Is this a caching problem? Is there a way to expire this somehow so users of the site will not be loading up old code from the previous release?

This is a specific problem with javascript files and css files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work:

I added a `?v=<%=DateTime.Now.Ticks%>` to the end of each css and js filename and this solved it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with that solution is that your users will always be downloading new css's and js's because `<%=DateTime.Now.Ticks%>` will be different in every refresh.
A better solution would be to concatenate the version of the application or even the last modified date of the file itself.